# Why am I getting this strange Python error? OSError: Unable to open file (File signature not found)

Tags: python, miniconda, oserror

I'm using a Python script in Miniconda to run through simulations that use a software called gprMax, a conda environment.
The script runs fine, and I get the desired output, but when I try to analyse the output, I get the following error:

`OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found)`

The code I run in Miniconda before the error is:

`python -m tools.plot_Ascan path_To_file/filename`

And the script I use in Miniconda is:

```
import numpy as np

n = 0
x_max = 500
y_max = 250

v1 = 0.02
v2 = 0.17
v3 = 0.27
v4 = 0.50
v5 = 0.04
for x1 in range(0, x_max-1):
    for y1 in range(0, y_max-1):
        w = np.random.random()
        xx1 = x1*0.002
        yy1 = y1*0.002
        
        if w < v1:
            print("#box: {} {} {} {} {} {} ilm".format(xx1, yy1, 0, xx1+0.002, yy1+0.002, 0.002))
        elif w > v1 and w < v1+v2:
            print("#box: {} {} {} {} {} {} oliv".format(xx1, yy1, 0, xx1+0.002, yy1+0.002, 0.002))
        elif w > v1+v2 and w < v3:
            print("#box: {} {} {} {} {} {} pyr".format(xx1, yy1, 0, xx1+0.002, yy1+0.002, 0.002))
        elif w > v3 and w < v3+v4:
            print("#box: {} {} {} {} {} {} plag".format(xx1, yy1, 0, xx1+0.002, yy1+0.002, 0.002))
        else:
            print("#box: {} {} {} {} {} {} free_space".format(xx1, yy1, 0, xx1+0.002, yy1+0.002, 0.002))
```

Like I said, the script runs fine in Miniconda, but conda seems to have trouble with the h5py file:

```
  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py\h5f.pyx", line 88, in h5py.h5f.open
OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found)
```

Comment: The file can not be opened. Either is does not exist or it is not in the right format.

Comment: If the file didn't exist, wouldn't I get a different error? It's more likely the file isn't in the right format but I don't see how I would change that.